# while uploading multiple files using multer in node js file is not created in destination directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

i have no errors and i got req.files in my console but the file is not created in destination directory

i have tried to upload images through multer
this code is admin controllers .js file

```
const storages = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./public/product");
    console.log(file)
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    console.log("gettin the filename")
  },
});

const multipleUpload = multer({ storages });

 adminAddproduct_post: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const product = new Products({
        product_id: randomId(len, pattern),
        productName: req.body.productName,
        productColor: req.body.productColor,
        productInStock: req.body.productInStock,
        productPrize: req.body.productPrice,
        productSize: req.body.productSize,
        productImage: req.files.map(file => Date.now() + file.originalname),
      });

    const result = await product.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("this is the " + err);
      } else {
        console.log("product save successfully");
      }
    });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    res.redirect("/admin/add-product")

  },
 storages: multipleUpload,
```

i can console req.files from adminAddProduct

this code in admin.js my route file

```
const {storages} = adminController
router.post("/add-product" , storages.array("uploads" , 4), adminController.adminAddproduct_post)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code where you are doing:- `productImage: req.files.map(file => Date.now() + file.originalname),`
Instead of it you can do:-

```
let filenames = req.files.map((file) => {
  return `${localhost:3000}/uploads/${file.filename}`;
});
```

below `const multipleUpload = multer({ storages });`
and you can put `productImage: filenames,` and save the product.

And you should also check in your model that you made the `productImage` as array like this `productImage: [{ type: String, required: true }],`

May this might be helpful to you!

Here is the code how I use to implement multer in my project:-

```js
import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";
import baseUrl from "../../helpers/baseUrl";

const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./public/uploads",
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      console.log(req.files);
      // console.log("files " + file);
      cb(
        null,
        req.files[0].fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + 
        path.extname(file.originalname)
      );
    },
  }),
});

// This is the middleware which I am using for my next js project.
apiRoute.use(upload.array("img", 5));

apiRoute.post(async (req, res) => {
  const products = await Product.find();
  console.log(req.files);
  let filenames = req.files.map((file) =>{
    return `${baseUrl}/uploads/${file.filename}`;
  })
  console.log("filenames: ", filenames);
  let p = new Product({
    title: req.body.title,
    slug: req.body.slug,
    desc: req.body.desc,
    img: filenames,
    category: req.body.category,
    size: req.body.size,
    color: req.body.color,
    price: req.body.price,
    availableQty: req.body.availableQty,
  });
  await p.save();
  res.status(200).json({ data: "success", products });
});
```

Comment: my data is succesfully saved in database but the file is not created in destination and my destination function is not working

Comment: you should be trying to give your destination in string like destination: "./public/uploads".

Comment: yes i tried that but no progress

Comment: try reinstalling multer package may it will help you

Comment: Mine multer object is like this:-                                                                                 const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./public/uploads",
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      console.log(req.files);
      // console.log("files " + file);
      cb(
        null,
        req.files[0].fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
      );
    },
  }),
});

Comment: no progress inside multer.diskStorage nothing is workinh

Comment: I think you don't have given the wrong pathname in destination

Comment: path checked its not the problem

Comment: then can you share your code with me in vs code using the live server extension

Comment: by which i can check the code and find the problem